# How to attach a list of strings to the main window in ObjC?

Tags: objective-c, list, panel

I have my main window and I'd like to attach a sheet to it: this sheet would list some strings and the user should choose one of them (double-clicking it, for example). Now: I know how to attach a sheet, so this is not a problem... but I DON'T know how to create such a sheet... In AppleScript is very simple: the command is "choose from list". How can I achieve the same thing in ObjC?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would usually do this with a custom `NSWindowController` that loads the sheet window from a nib. The list is typically implemented as an `NSTableView`. It's a bit too complex of a topic to describe each individual step here. The [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Introduction/Introduction.html) could help you getting started with the list part.

Comment: Yes, I know I can do that but I was wondering if there was something as simple as the AS' "choose from list"... I fear there isn't...

Comment: No, there isn't, though you could use AppleScript from Cocoa, using `NSAppleScript`.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to use a sheet like this though (a modal dialog should work) and it's not a very elegant approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I already use Applescript in my ObjC app, even if I don't use NSApplescript but AppleScriptObjC. It doesn't matter, I can live with "choose from list", it's ok... I was looking for a way to attach that sheet to the main window. The problem is I don't have any outlet pointing to that AS sheet... and I don't think there is any way to get it.